# gitolite git clone ssh:// works but git clone git:// doesn't for few directories

Tags: git, gitolite

I have this problem:

I could `git clone git@myserver.com:myrepo` repos on my gitolite server. After that I installed git-daemon to be able to do the same with git protocol. Now I can `git clone git://myserver.com/myrepo` only those repos which has not been cloned with ssh protocol.
For the other repos I get:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

At the same time I didn't see those repositories on gitweb, but I did:
`usermod -a -G git www-data` # where www-data is the user that hosts apache2
`chmod -R 0755 /path/to/my/gitolite/repositories/`

And now I see all the repos on gitweb.

I guess those issues are related, but I can't find out why or how.

I don't have any complicated `.gitolite.rc` configuration, I only changed `UMASK from 0077 to 0027`

All repositories belong to `git` user in `git` group.

If you need any more details, just ask for them :) Any help or suggestion appretiated!

Comment: Why would you use a git daemon, which has no authentication and would bypass completely the authorization layer which is gitolite?

Comment: Because we block outgoing and incoming git protocol requests with a firewall, and in our internal network we want to grant access freely for all developers, so they don't need me to add their key. Also we use yocto-project and all our recipes using git protocol to download the source.

Comment: Ok. I prefer setting up an apache server myself, rather than using git daemon.

Comment: Thank you VonC! I understand your point. In the meantime I found the solution for the problem.

Comment: Excellent. You can add it as an answer, and even select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I misconfigured the git-daemon. In the `/etc/sv/git-daemon/run` file I had `-ugitdaemon switch` instead of `-ugitdaemon:gitolite`.

This [article](http://computercamp.cdwilson.us/git-gitolite-git-daemon-gitweb-setup-on-ubunt) lead me to solve the problem.

Comment: good catch, I am not familiar with the git-daemon options. +1